# Is there a way to define a filesystemwatcher only for the first renaming of a file?

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a PowerShell script that is using filesystemwatcher to monitor a defined folder. The scenario is that colleagues from another team drop a folder there with data to be processed. That folder has a certain naming convention (begins with yyyy-mm-dd). The script watches for both Created and Renamed events because they keep creating folders directly in the monitored path which results in initial name of folder to be 'New Folder' and then they rename it. Now, sometimes I need to rename that folder again (more semantically), which fires yet another event and floods mailboxes of all those that are notified by Send-MailMessage that event is firing (i.e. the client, PM, etc.).

```
function fileWatcher {
param (
    [string]$Path
)

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path = $Path
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter = "20*"
$Action = {
    $Object = "<a href='{0}'>{0}</a> was created at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
    $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
    $Event.TimeGenerated
    $WriteHostParams = @{
        ForegroundColor = 'Green'
        BackgroundColor = 'Black'
        Object          = $Object
    }
    try {
        Send-MailMessage -From 'example@example.com' -To 'example2@example.com' -Subject "New Backlog Folder ready to be Loaded" -Body $Object  -SmtpServer 'smtp.example.com' -ErrorAction Stop -BodyAsHtml
        Write-Host @WriteHostParams
    }
    catch { write-host "send failed" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White } }

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher Created -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher Renamed -Action $Action
```

I expect that only the initial creation as per the naming convention and the first renaming of the file would trigger an event. Any subsequent renamings would be left unnoticed.

Comment: Did you try [Unregister-Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Unregister-Event?view=powershell-6)?

Comment: Hi Moerwald! Thanks for asking but I still need the event — to watch for changes in the defined folder (there are new folders constantly created and being correctly named).